# changing a TextField while editing another TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I recently started learning SwiftUI and I want to make a unit converter. In the process I ran into a problem: it is necessary to make sure that when a numerical value is entered into one of the TextField, the rest of the TextField formulas are triggered and the total values are displayed.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var celsius: String = ""
    @State var kelvin: String = ""
    @State var farenheit: String = ""
    @State var reyumur: String = ""
    @State var rankin: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Temperature(celsius: $celsius, kelvin: $kelvin, farenheit: $farenheit, reyumur: $reyumur, rankin: $rankin)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Temperature: View {
    @Binding var celsius: String
    @Binding var kelvin: String
    @Binding var farenheit: String
    @Binding var reyumur: String
    @Binding var rankin: String
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(
                header: Text("Международная система (СИ)")) {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter value", text: $celsius)
                        .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        .onReceive(Just(celsius)) { newValue in
                            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) }
                            if filtered != newValue {
                                self.celsius = filtered
                            }
                        }
                    Text("°C")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter value", text: $kelvin)
                        .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        .onReceive(Just(kelvin)) { newValue in
                            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) }
                            if filtered != newValue {
                                self.kelvin = filtered
                            }
                        }
                    Text("K")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            Section(
                header: Text("США и Британия")) {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter value" , text: $farenheit)
                        .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        .onReceive(Just(farenheit)) { newValue in
                            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) }
                            if filtered != newValue {
                                self.farenheit = filtered
                            }
                        }
                    Text("F")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            Section(
                header: Text("Редкоиспользуемые")) {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter value" , text: $reyumur)
                        .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        .onReceive(Just(reyumur)) { newValue in
                            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) }
                            if filtered != newValue {
                                self.reyumur = filtered
                            }
                        }
                    Text("Re")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter value" , text: $rankin)
                        .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                        .onReceive(Just(rankin)) { newValue in
                            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.".contains($0) }
                            if filtered != newValue {
                                self.rankin = filtered
                            }
                        }
                    Text("R")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Temperature")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but there is a `decimalPad` keyboard providing exactly the characters you want.

Answer (score 0):

With SwiftUI 3, `@FocusState` can be used to detect if `TextField` is focused, which enables doing different works according to its value. You could set one variable to be the main, and other values should be calculated from it. For each value, calculate in the forward and reverse direction with two functions:

```swift
struct CelsiusAndKelvin: View {
    @State private var celsius: String = ""  // Assume all other values are based on celsius
    
    @FocusState private var isKelvinFocused: Bool  // When focused,
    @State private var kelvinWhenFocused: String?  // you may not want it to be calculated from other values
    private var kelvinMask: Binding<String> {
        Binding {  // If `isKelvinFocused` turns true, this getter will be called first
            if isKelvinFocused && kelvinWhenFocused != nil {
                return kelvinWhenFocused!
            }
            
            if let x = Double(celsius) {
                return String(format: "%.2f", c2k(x))
            }
            
            return ""
        } set: {
            if isKelvinFocused { kelvinWhenFocused = $0 }
            
            if let x = Double($0) {
                celsius = String(format: "%.2f", k2c(x))
            } else {
                celsius = ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("°C", text: $celsius)
            TextField("K", text: kelvinMask)
                .focused($isKelvinFocused)
        }
        .onChange(of: isKelvinFocused) {
            // Make `isKelvinFocused` always equal to `kelvinWhenFocused != nil`
            if !$0 { kelvinWhenFocused = nil }
        }
    }
}

extension CelsiusAndKelvin {
    private func c2k(_ x: Double) -> Double {
        return x + 273.15
    }
    
    private func k2c(_ x: Double) -> Double {
        return x - 273.15
    }
}
```